# SQL Server database creation trouble with deleting FK

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query for creating all my tables but since I am still making it I want to be able to run execute over and over again without having issues such as table already exists, etc.

So I have been trying for a while now to write a query that will delete a table and remake it. It has a foreign key and it wont let me do it.

Here are my tables:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Employees') IS NOT NULL               
    DROP Table Employees                               

CREATE TABLE Employees 
(
     eID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     eName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     uID int NOT NULL,
);

IF OBJECT_ID('eA') IS NOT NULL /* checks if exists*/
    DROP Table eA                  /*removes */

CREATE TABLE eA 
(
    aID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    eID int NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_MadeUpName 
         FOREIGN KEY (eID) REFERENCES Employees(eID),
);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[eA] 
DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_MadeUpName]
```

The get this error:

> Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 47
>   Could not drop object 'Employees' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
>
> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 49
>   There is already an object named 'Employees' in the database.

EDIT********************
I had a spelling error....LOL the following works. I put it before the creating of the Employees table. 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[eA] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_MadeUpName]

Thanks all!

Comment: Since you know you already have this table why not create alter statements instead of dropping the table and recreating it? You will have to repopulate all the data if you drop it.

Answer (score 0):

ordinal position issue.

> Drop FK to Employee table
>
> Drop Employee table
>
> -> add employee table
>
> Drop EA table
>
> -> add ea table
>
> Add FK to Employee table

optionally you could just do the whole thing backwards

> Drop EA table
>
> Add EA table
>
> -> no FK in table definition
>
> Drop Employee table
>
> -> add employee table
>
> Add FK to employee table

Answer (score 0):

You can disable foreign key constraints temporarily in your database and then run your query, and after your query enable this.

like this:

```
-- disable all constraints
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

after your query enable all constraints

```
-- enable all constraints

    exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?'", @command2="ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```